# Why are the contents of my array being printed twice in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, console-application

I do not understand why this code prints the contents of the array twice.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Int64 userlength;
    Int64 userlengthcounter;
    String unencrypted;
    char current;
    start:
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many characters the string you want encrypyted to be:");
    userlength = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the string you want to be encrypted:");
    unencrypted = Console.ReadLine();
    int[] first = new int[userlength];
    int[] second = new int[userlength];
    if (userlength != unencrypted.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The string you entered was not the same length as the number of characters you specified");
        goto start;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < userlength; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(unencrypted[i]);
        current = unencrypted[i];
        first[i] = current;

    }
    foreach (char item in first)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

For example entering abcd would return abcdabcd and i don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Side note: PLEASE stop using `goto`.

Comment: Are you saying the output is all on _one_ line like that?  Not on separate lines?  Could there be _two different places_ that you _write lines_?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: As yet another side note, you don't need to ask the user the length, just ask the string directly, the length can be computed from it. And you get rid of the validation, multiple questions and most important the `goto`.

Comment: Can anyone explain why using goto is a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have *two* loops, first you print each character in `unencrypted` in the `for` loop and store the chars in `first` array.

Then you loop over the array and print the chars again with `foreach`.

Additional Note: Using `goto` is almost *always* a bad idea because it makes your code hard to follow and unreadable. Because you have to manually track where the code jumps.

You can do the same thing with a `do-while` loop instead.

```
do { 
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many characters the string you want encrypyted to be:");
     userlength = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter the string you want to be encrypted:");
     unencrypted = Console.ReadLine();
     int[] first = new int[userlength];
     int[] second = new int[userlength];

     if (userlength != unencrypted.Length)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("The string you entered was not the same length as the number of characters you specified");
     }   
} while(userlength != unencrypted.Length);
```

Comment: Might want to include why `goto` is such a bad idea.  This is a big teaching moment / learning opportunity

Comment: @maccettura it's already mentioned in the comment but I have added an explanation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you specifically build "first" then you print it in foreach, basically displaying the same content twice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userlength; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(unencrypted[i]);
    current = unencrypted[i];
    first[i] = current;
}

foreach (char item in first)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```